# Eventlistener function requires two clicks

Tags: javascript

I just started JS and trying to get a button which opens a block of text and with this same button you can close the block. All works fine but the first click is doing the focus and second click is opening the block of text. Block of text needs to open on the first click.

Hope you can help me out with plain JS...Thanks!

```
document.getElementById("homeBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("parText");
    var y = document.getElementById("homeBtn");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.innerHTML = "Sluiten";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.innerHTML = "Lees verder...";
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="homeBtn">Lees verder...</button>
</div>
<div id="parText">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Etiam sed leo felis. Maecenas tincidunt orci id orci vulputate congue. 
    Aliquam in molestie tortor. Sed erat felis, tincidunt id commodo sit amet, 
    dignissim fringilla metus. Proin porta, justo eget sollicitudin hendrerit, 
    sapien ligula imperdiet erat, vel hendrerit odio quam ut mauris. 
    Etiam laoreet justo massa, ac pretium sem pharetra at. Nullam ut felis orci. 
    Duis faucibus mauris libero, at semper nulla finibus vitae. In ut ex justo.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add that code on below of html tag

Comment: Seems to work on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f0t58w8/), do you expect different behaviour?

Comment: in the html file im having the same issue

Comment: Please post a full example, including the relevant part of the HTML.

Comment: see original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `display` to `none` first. When your code is running it goes to the else part and then it is setting the `display` to `none`, so nothing is happening. When you click again the `if` statement is now true as the `display` is set to `none` and the code works. I have fixed your code. Check the snippet.

```js
var y = document.getElementById("homeBtn");
var x = document.getElementById("parText");
x.style.display = "none";
y.addEventListener("click", function(){
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.innerHTML = "Sluiten";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.innerHTML = "Lees verder...";
}
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="homeBtn">Lees verder...</button>
<div id="parText">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Etiam sed leo felis. Maecenas tincidunt orci id orci vulputate congue. 
Aliquam in molestie tortor. Sed erat felis, tincidunt id commodo sit amet, 
dignissim fringilla metus. Proin porta, justo eget sollicitudin hendrerit, 
sapien ligula imperdiet erat, vel hendrerit odio quam ut mauris. 
Etiam laoreet justo massa, ac pretium sem pharetra at. Nullam ut felis orci. 
Duis faucibus mauris libero, at semper nulla finibus vitae. In ut ex justo.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you!